# Counter Not being changed

Tags: javascript, html

Doing a project on a counter that can be changed by buttons, however the counter won't change. Chrome inspect element debug console thing isn't finding anything either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br>
<font size="4">
    <h1 align="center">Counter</h1>
</font>
<font size="5">
    <h2 align="center" id="counter">0</h2>
</font>
<div align="center">
    <br>
    <button onclick="decrease()" >Decrease</button>
    <button onclick="reset()" >Reset</button>
    <button onclick="increase()" >Increase</button>
</div>
<script>
    var counterNum
    function decrease() {
        counterNum = counterNum - 1
        document.getElementById("counter").value = ""+ counterNum;
    }
    function reset() {
        counterNum = counterNum * 0
        document.getElementById("counter").value = ""+ counterNum;
    }
    function increase() {
        counterNum = counterNum + 1
        document.getElementById("counter").value = ""+ counterNum;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- You have to initalize `counterNum` to `0`, otherwise its default value is `undefined`, which, when incremented, is `NaN`
- You are modifying the element's `value`, which does not affect the element's content. Instead, assign `counterNum` to the element's `textContent` or `innerHTML`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br>
<font size="4">
    <h1 align="center">Counter</h1>
</font>
<font size="5">
    <h2 align="center" id="counter">0</h2>
</font>
<div align="center">
    <br>
    <button onclick="decrease()" >Decrease</button>
    <button onclick="reset()" >Reset</button>
    <button onclick="increase()" >Increase</button>
</div>
<script>
    var counterNum = 0
    function decrease() {
        counterNum = counterNum - 1
        document.getElementById("counter").textContent = ""+ counterNum;
    }
    function reset() {
        counterNum = counterNum * 0
        document.getElementById("counter").textContent = ""+ counterNum;
    }
    function increase() {
        counterNum = counterNum + 1
        document.getElementById("counter").textContent = ""+ counterNum;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the only difference changing the .value to .innerHTML? If so, why? I did this other project where you clicked a picture and it increased a number in an input box and .value worked? Could you tell me what the difference is?

Comment: @Atramentis for input elements, `value` defines the data. For `div` elements, the `value` attribute does not affect the output.

Comment: So if I used <input> instead of <h2> .value would work? also does .innerHTML work with both?

Comment: Im blind I thought you changed ```.value``` to ```.innerHTML``` my bad. So ```.value``` is for ```<input>``` and ```.textContent```?

Comment: @Atramentis `value` would work for the `input`, not the `h2`. `innerHTML` should be used for the `h2`.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see the explanation at the top! Thanks so much for the help @StackSlave and Spectric

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a `constructor` or `class`. Of course, you should use external CSS and JavaScript so it's cached. Here's my two cents:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, Counter; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{ // reduce code you will reuse a lot
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id); mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.add(...classNames);
  return aC;
}
rC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.remove(...classNames);
  return rC;
}
tC = (node, className)=>{
  node.classList.toggle(className);
  return tC;
}
Counter = function(start = 0, minLimit = -Infinity){
  this.count = start; this.minLimit = minLimit;
  this.increase = (by = 1)=>{
    this.count += by;
    return this;
  }
  this.decrease = (by = 1)=>{
    if(this.count > this.minLimit)this.count -= by;
    return this;
  }
  this.reset = (to = 0)=>{
    this.count = to;
    return this;
  }
}
// small library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load Event (except // end load line)
// get elements only once if you can
const counter = new Counter, counter_val = I('counter_val');
I('decrease').onclick = ()=>{
  counter_val.textContent = counter.decrease().count;
}
I('reset').onclick = ()=>{
  counter_val.textContent = counter.reset().count;
}
I('increase').onclick = ()=>{
  counter_val.textContent = counter.increase().count;
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; margin:0;
}
h1,h2{
  margin:0;
}
.center{
  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; flex-wrap:wrap; width:100%; height:100%;
}
.center>*{
  width:100%; text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Counter</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='center'>
    <h1 id='counter_title'>Counter</h1>
    <h2 id='counter_val'>0</h2>
    <div id='counter_buttons'>
      <button id='decrease' type='button'>Decrease</button>
      <button id='reset' type='button'>Reset</button>
      <button id='increase' type='button'>Increase</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I removed your depreciated `<font>` tags. Of course, you've noticed that you need to initialize your counter to a Number, instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm extremely new to coding and thus don't know any CSS. I also don't know what caches are nor anything else lol.